# Reports with custom object

Tags: custom-object, custom-reports

We have custom object custom_obj  and this object is related to contact using R_Contact__r.externalId .

This is all working fine and we are doing sync of data using bulk API in contact as well as on custom_obj.

When we create report -> new report and choose other report WE see two items there

1. custom_obj
2. custom_obj_with_contacts

When we select #1, we are able to see data and able to create reports.But when we select #2 , we don't see any data. Not seeing any other option . What is missing here ?
Any pointers on what should i check?

Comment: Have you verified that the contacts are in fact connected to the custom object via a lookup field after your data load? If they're not, this could just be a result of the report's join type.

Comment: I checked data by querying SOQL on dev tools. Data seems correct and lookup to contact exists. Is there any other way i can do this verification?

Comment: I'd create a custom Report Type for this object combination and see if it works that way.

Comment: Thanks David . So something weird happening. I am able to create custom report type but only relation I am able to create is from Contact to Custom Obj & this works fine and gives data and i am able to create report .  However In my definition custom object has Contact__r.externalId so wouldn't it make sense to create relation from custom obj to contact

Comment: Is the custom object an External Object?

Comment: No its normal custom object

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you mean when you say "In my definition custom object has Contact__r.externalId". Is there a standard lookup relationship between the custom object and Contact?

Comment: Yes there is field "contact" which of Type Lookup(Contact) .

Comment: You should be able to create report relating Contact to Custom Object, or a Custom Object report with Contact fields added to the report canvas via [Add fields related via lookup](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_report_type_layouts.htm&type=5). You can't define the report type by the relationship starting from the Custom Object to the Contact.

Comment: what about sharing rules on your Contact? maybe you're not seeing them with the second report type due to sharing rules. also are you making sure that you are selecting "All..." not just "My..." in the report builder?

Comment: Sahring rules has Publi Read write. Yes I am selecting all in report

Comment: @DavidReed You mean I should be able to have report generated both ways? What would I be missing as I dont see that.    #2 : The default report type which is available does not fetch data. I am clueless on that too Its name is something like "Custom Object with Contact"

Answer (score 0):

Inside Setup open "**Report Types**" and Select "custom_obj_with_contacts" report type.

Edit it, it will open a UI that will select the fields which you want your report to have access.

[image]

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_reports_create_report_types.htm

Comment: Thanks Pranay. But when i went to Report Types . I did not see any report type. Bascially we haven't created any report type. These seems like automatically available when created custom_obj and second one because relation between custom_obj and contact

Comment: Field level security would be my next guess. Can you check that?

Comment: When i checked look up Contact field level security , It looked fine . For all users it is "Visible" and Read only ..